# Dealing with massive amounts of data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am building a machine learning platform which has a react frontend, we are visually rendering machine learning models in scatterplot format. The issue arises when we have "larger" datasets, for example 400k+ rows of data. Currently I am storing all of the data for the charts in a redux store. Is there is a better way to handle large amounts of data on the frontend? aka storing the data in state/redux store.

Comment: Why do you need to store that much data on the front end?  Are you actually trying to display it all at once?  If so, how?  In a table?  Or in a scatterplot?  We need more information to give advice for your specific situation.

Comment: Hi Seth, I am displaying it in a table using react-virtualzed, and a scatterplot using highcharts. So yes I am trying to display it all at once. TY for your response! I think a better question would be, is there a better way to store data that has to be rendered all it once, if not in redux/state.

Comment: I was going to mention react virtualized, so you're going in the right direction there.  What issues are you having?  Food for thought: here's no way that your users need to see all 400k+ rows of data, or individual points on a scatterplot, so I think you're going to have to reconsider your data structures / api design.  Is your project using redux?  There's just not enough info for us to give you a good answer here.

Comment: use pagination and request the data according to the page.

Comment: The main issue is that I'm storing large amounts of data (400k rows) in a redux store, which consumes a lot of memory and slows the page down. Since we would like to render all of the data on the page is there a way to visualize large amounts of data without storing it in redux? Or is this not feasible in the browser.